# Getting sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-security

1. I am using oracle java 11 2. Sping boot version-3 and 3.Rest template to call the API.

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.set("api-key",key);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", httpHeaders);
ResponseEntity<String> resp = rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

I have tried the below steps to solve the problem.

1. Uploaded the certificates using [InstallCert.java](https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/180292346/InstallCert.java?version=1&modificationDate=1315453596921) to the java cacerts location.
2. I can see the success message for the certificate upload.
3. Restarted the application and hit the URL again.

Even after trying the above solution still get the Same exception. I have tried the solution given for the issue on StackOverflow but the result is the same.

Comment: You don't need that special bit of Java code (InstallCert.java); use the [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html#GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549) tool that comes with the JDK to install the certificate that your application needs to trust.

Comment: Even I have tried Keytool but I am getting the same exception. keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mdecert -file C:\temp\mdeCert.cer -keystore cacerts